# What is the alternative to using the 'new' keyword in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
function car( make, model, year ){

 this.make = make;
 this.model = model;
 this.year = year;

}

var car1 = new car( "toyota", "supra", 1995 );
var car2 = new car( "nissan", "gtr", "1999" );
```

can I create car3 with the object syntax without specifying the keys in the object make, model and year? example

```
car3 {
 make: "mazda", 
 model: "rx7",
 year: "2002"
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. You say you want to "*create car3 ... without specifying the make, model and year*". Then what *do* you want to specify? Do you just want an empty object?

Comment: without specifying the word "make" the word "model" and the word "year" but I do want to specify the values

Comment: I think you need to expand the example to show what it is you want exactly

Comment: @nacholibre: new does not create a new instance of the function. It creates a new object and uses the function as the constructor.

Comment: @chiccodoro you are right :)

Comment: trying to adapt the thinking mentioned in this blog post
http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/11/13/javascript-we-hardly-new-ya/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another option:

```
var car1 = {make: "nissan", model: "gtr",year: "1999" }
```

You can also create an empty car(make\year\model will be undefined) like this:

```
var car1 = {};
```

or

```
var car1 = new car();
```

You can later fill it up with:

```
car1.make = "nissan";
```

Comment: I think the answer is perfectly correct and answers the question. Don't see a reason to downvote. (I recognize that I came to completely different approaches, but given the very open question it is hard to give a "wrong" or "bad" answer at all.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: No. I don't exactly see the point of your question. In both examples you specify the make, model, and year. So here my two guesses:

First guess. You want a constructor without parameters - this is simple, since parameter values can be omitted in JavaScript:

```
function car( make, model, year ) {
    this.make = make || "";
    this.model = model || "";
    this.year = year || 0;
}
```

Second guess. You would like to use object notation because you like it. The object notation creates an object without using your constructor function, but you could use the object as input:

```
function car( parameters ) {
    this.make = parameters.make;
    this.model = parameters.model;
    this.year = parameters.year;
}

var car = new car( { make: "mazda", model: "rx7", year: "2002" });
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is one more alternative:

```
function car(a,b,c){
  return {
    a:a, b:b, c:c 
  };
}
var x = car(1,2,3);
var y = car(4,5,6);
```

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript you must either use the keyword "new" to create Objects.

Using the code:

```
var car = {make: "nissan", model: "gtr, year: "1999"}
```

Would make a JSON containing those attributes, but not a car.

You can check if you are making a "car" object or not with this code:

```
//var obj previously defined/set/created
if(obj instanceof car) { /*code to confirm class*/ }
```

Comment: disagree. You don't have to use "new" to create an object, and your first code snippet does not create JSON but it creates an object. JSON is a serialization format, not a JavaScript entity. It is often mixed up with JS objects because JSON is derived from (or more precise, a subset of) the JavaScript object literal syntax. The only reason to use `new` is to use a constructor function for creating the object thus giving the object a certain "prototype".

Comment: When I used a "if(car instanceof car)" it did not verify using the first example.